# Polymer - Internal elements visible in Chrome's elements browser

Tags: google-chrome, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I just started learning Polymer, and I've been working through their docs. I have created a very simple Hello World element that seems to be working for me:

```
<link rel="import" href="/path/to/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="test-element">
    <template>
        <style>
            p {
                color: blue;
            }
        </style>
        <p>Hello [[name]]!</p>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'test-element',
            properties: {
                name: String
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

I can import and use the element on a page successfully:

```
<link rel="import" href="/path/to/my/test-element.html">
<test-element name="World"></test-element>
```

That correctly shows a blue 'p' element saying "Hello World!", and I can also see that the CSS styling on the element is correctly not bleeding into other 'p' elements on the page outside of the element.

So far so good. However, in the docs I've been reading that one of the benefits of a web component is that its internal implementation details are hidden from the main DOM tree. Their given example was the 'video' element, which has other elements inside it, but you can't query those directly.

In the Chrome developer tools, however, I am able to see the 'p' element in the DOM tree inside my 'test-element'. I can even query it with jQuery, which I thought I was not supposed to be able to do:

```
$("test-element p")
// Produces: [ <p class="style-scope test-element">Hello World!</p> ]
```

Am I doing something wrong, or have I misunderstood the way Polymer works?

Comment: Can you try this same test after enabling `shadow-dom`. [Here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings) is how to do it.

Comment: Awesome that worked, I'm not able to query internal elements anymore on browsers that support the shadow DOM. If you could post your comment as an answer, I'll upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind what you see is `shady-dom`. Polymer by default implements `shady-dom` instead of `shadow-dom`(also the reason why we use `lite` version of `webcomponentsjs`, no shadow-dom present) as out of 3 major browsers (chrome, safari and firefox) currently only chrome has support and `shadow-dom` and using `shadow-dom` from `polyfill(webcomponentsjs)` is very costly (and some other reasons). `shady-dom` has its own downsides which includes the one that you observed and some other. You can read more about `shadow` and `shady` dom [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/blog/shadydom.html).

**Note:** You can still see `shadow-dom`'s inner element in your `chrome dev-tool` if  you enable `Show user agent shadow DOM` option in devtool settings, but this time with a different NodeList structure.

[image]

For those browsers that do support it (i.e. Chrome), you can enable Shadow DOM when it is present by setting the global 'dom' Polymer setting to 'shadow' (see the [Polymer Docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings) for more details):

```
window.Polymer = {
  dom: 'shadow'
};
```